# TextField Autocompletion with JSON Response

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json, autocomplete

**What I want :**

I want to use Auto Completion of Text field in my App.As my data is coming from the web service, I want to perform the "Auto Completion" with the JSON Response.

**What I Know :**

I know that first I have to fetch data from the web service. Then I need to parse it and fill the Array with that parsed data and then I can use that array to perform Auto Completion.

**Problem :**

I don't know how to send the requests to get JSON data for each "prefix" that user types in text field (means I want JSON Data during Typing). I know how to perform "JSON Parsing" and "Auto completion of text fields" independently but no idea regarding "TextField Autocompletion with JSON Response". I tried a lot to find the answer regarding this but i failed. So Please Help me...

I am using the [doautocompletetextfield](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/doautocompletetextfield) to perform **"Text field Auto completion"**.

Better Suggestion for this problem will be appreciated.

**Any Solutions ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linear searching just like done in the api example or can use NSPredicate for fast searching in your autoCompleteArray.

According to your problem, you will get json data first, then you need to save relevant data from json into some array and then you can use this api to autocomplete the text in text field.

But i am confused about your this statement: "I don't know how to send the requests to get JSON data for each "prefix" that user types in text field." 
1) Do you want to get json data from web service during typing? 
2) Or you want to fetch data from json dictionary during typing?

If you want to go with option (1), i think it would be bad way to solve the problem.
And if you want to go with option (2) then you need to parse json and extract data of your interest and save it in an array. And then do autocomplete on the basis of the contents of that array.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to go for the first option that you mentioned in your answer. I know that it is a bad option. But I have "World City Names" as a response in JSON Parsing. So if i will go with option 2 , a Large Amount of response data needs to be handled in array. I scared that might result in the crash of app. So please give me some relevant answer or if you have any other solution... Hope you are understanding my problem.

Comment: One solution can be: 1- Send an asynchronous get request in which you will send your being typed text i-e prefix as get query parameter. 2- You need to implement search on server which will return json response according to your typed prefix. 3- Then you give that json data's result to your autocompletion text array... This solution need fast searching at server side like google search engine :)

Comment: Yes you are right... That's not the solution. So I am thinking something different about that Issue. In between I came across one another issue of "Handling Multiple JSON Responses". As I don't have any experience to work with Web services , I don't know how to solve this problem. So if you can provide me some link for the custom class which can collect JSON data and store them in an array, i will be very thankful to you... Please give some instant reply.

Comment: Thanks iMemon for your explanation and time. I worked on your explanation and managed to get the solution of the question.