# How would I go about auto populating a UISearch field with data from a JSON web feed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

How would I go about auto populating a `UISearchBar` field with data from a `JSON` web feed? I have access to a list of cities via a `JSON` feed and would like to display them in the `UISearchBar` field so that if the user starts typing "San..." then San Diego auto completes for them. It would change if "San F.." was entered and auto display "San Francisco" etc...

I'm dealing with city names and don't want the user to misspell a city and get no results because of it.

thanks for any help

Comment: I had similar Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948710/textfield-autocompletion-with-json-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

if ([searchText length] != 0)
{

    [searchArray removeAllObjects];

    for (get every city name from original array)
    {
        NSRange titleResultsRange = [cityname rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0 )

            <add that object into searchArray]

           //NSLog(@"items is %@",_items);
    }

}

[self.tableViewItems reloadData];

}
```